# PostgreSQL Error: Connection to the database failed: Server Closed the connection unexpectedly

Tags: database, postgresql, database-administration, postgresql-12

when I connect to the PostgreSQL Database from localhost then sometimes it gives `Error: Server Closed the connection unexpectedly` although when execute the command again immediately then connection gets established. but it become a problem because I am using batch files for backups. and sometimes pg_dumpall and pg_dump command also gives `Error: Server Closed the connection unexpectedly`. and this interrupts my scheduled backups. I have PostgreSQL 12.10 installed on Windows.

Comment: Does this occur immediately upon trying to connect, or does it occur after the connection is already established?  Is there a corresponding message in the database log file?

Comment: Yes, This occurs immediately upon trying to connect.